# Multiple AJAX responses

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a page where a user can "view more info", an ID is sent to a php page which then queries the database. It then returns some data, with some of the data I want to put this into a textarea, the other into a standard div.

How can I send multiple responses back, and how do I know what the data is? e.g. send name and address, how do I know what the php page is sending back so that I can interpret the data on client side?

Is there a better way than using

`httpxml.responseText.indexOf("something")`

As the two responses may contain similar data? What I hope to do is send two variables from the PHP page and then "see" these variables on client side?

Hope I haven't made this too confusing, thanks.

Javascript only please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return JSON containing all your values from the PHP.  Then after getting the response your javascript can do whatever you'd like to do with the values.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

--PHP--

```
$responseArr = array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2);
echo json_encode($responseArr);
```

If I remember correctly (i do this with jQuery now), just performing eval() on your response text will form the object for you.

--javascript-- (just vanilla js right? you didnt mention jQuery or anything)
this is probably inside your onreadystatechange block

```
var r = xhr.responseText;   //assuming you name the XMLHttpRequest object 'xhr'
var rlist = eval('('+r+')');
document.getElementByID("foo").innerHTML = rlist['a']; //or whatever you want to do with these
document.getElementByID("bar").innerHTML = rlist['b'];
```

Comment: Thanks ! I just spend that last 20mins trying to figure that out haha, seems I tried to load the array within the eval function. Thanks again :).